# getting error when sending files to backend react node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, next.js, backend

I am getting error of undefined when i send a file from react to backend,
i am unable to understand the error.
i am sending a image which will be uploaded in cloudinary but my backend could not get the image data i don't know why this happening.
here's the code

My React js code

```
  const handleFileUpload = async (e)=>{
    setprofilePic({file: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])});

    const imageFile = e.target.files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', imageFile);

    const result = await fetch(`${host}/fgrapi/auth/setprofileimg`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data" ,
        'auth-token': localStorage.getItem('token')
      },
      body: formData
    })
    const data = await result.json();

  }
```

My Backend Code (I am using controllers)
Routes

```
router.put('/setprofileimg', fetchuser, authController.setProfileImage)
```

```
setProfileImage: async (req, res)=>{
        try{
            userId = req.user.id;
            const image = req.files;
            console.log(image);   //I am getting undefined here
            cloudinary.uploader.upload(image.tempFilePath, async function (error, result) {
                const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {profilepic: result.secure_url}, {new: true});
            });
        }
        catch(error){
            console.error(error.message);
            res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error Occured");
        }
    },
```

My server file

```
const express = require('express');
const connectToMongo = require('./db');
const cors = require('cors')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

connectToMongo();
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 1000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(fileUpload({
    useTempFiles: true
}));
app.use(express.json());

// Available routes
app.use('/fgrapi/auth', require('./routes/auth'));

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("Connection Success");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a middleware for handling multipart/form-data in your backend.
Use multer or some other available pkg for reading form-data.

You can refer from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer